# `sapply` is successful for "zoo" object but not "xts" object, why?

Tags: r, dataframe, xts, zoo, sapply

Here is an example that is showing a clear difference between "zoo" and "xts".

```
library(xts)

mydf = as.data.frame(replicate(6, sample(c(1:10), 10, rep = T)))
myzoo = zoo(mydf, order.by = Sys.Date() + 1:10)
resultzoo = sapply(myzoo, function(x) x+1)
```

Although I am losing the date (which is a behaviour already commented [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/39180/best-way-to-apply-across-an-xts-object)), the code above works fine. However, the code below gives error

```
myxts = xts(mydf, order.by = Sys.Date() + 1:10)
resultxts = sapply(myxts, function(x) x+1)
# Error in array(r, dim = d, dimnames = if (!(is.null(n1 <- names(x[[1L]])) &  : 
# length of 'dimnames' [1] not equal to array extent
```

I cannot find any explanation for this weird behaviour. Any idea is welcome.

Comment: Note that `sapply` is meant to be called with a list for the first argument, `X`. And `X` will be coerced to a list if it is not one. A better alternative to calling `sapply` on an zoo/xts object is to just use `apply(X, 2, FUN)` to loop over columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have raised a very good question. Before making my answer, I would like to comment that you can use

```
sapply(myzoo, "+", 1)
sapply(myxts, "+", 1)
```

instead of

```
sapply(myzoo, function (x) x + 1)
sapply(myxts, function (x) x + 1)
```

This is because `"+"` is already a function. Try `1 + 2` and `"+"(1, 2)`.

---

`sapply` takes two stages. The first stage is an ordinary call to `lapply`; the second stage is a call to `simplify2array` for result simplification. The error message you get announces that something wrong happens in the second stage. Indeed, if we try:

```
x1 <- lapply(myzoo, "+", 1)
x2 <- lapply(myxts, "+", 1)
```

we get no error at all!

However, if we compare `x1` and `x2`, we will see the difference. For neatness I will just extract the first list element:

```
x1[[1]]

#2016-09-30 2016-10-01 2016-10-02 2016-10-03 2016-10-04 2016-10-05 2016-10-06 
#         3          4          5          7          2          2          4 
#2016-10-07 2016-10-08 2016-10-09 
#         3          5          3 

x2[[1]]

#           V1
#2016-09-30  3
#2016-10-01  4
#2016-10-02  5
#2016-10-03  7
#2016-10-04  2
#2016-10-05  2
#2016-10-06  4
#2016-10-07  3
#2016-10-08  5
#2016-10-09  3
```

Ah, for "zoo" object, dimension is dropped so we get a vector; while for "xts" object, dimension is not dropped hence we get a single column matrix!

It is exactly for this reason that `sapply` fails. By default, the simplification option for `sapply` is `simplify = TRUE` which always tries to simplify to a 1D vector or a 2D matrix. For `x1`, this is no problem; but for `x2`, this is impossible.

If we use a milder setting: `simplify = "array"`, we will get appropriate behaviour:

1. `sapply(myzoo, "+", 1, simplify = "array")` gives a 2D array (i.e., a matrix you see);
2. `sapply(myxts, "+", 1, simplify = "array")` gives a **3D array**.

---

From this example, we can see that `sapply` is not always desirable. Why not use the following:

```
y1 <- do.call(cbind, x1)
y2 <- do.call(cbind, x2)

#           V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6
#2016-09-30  3  8  6  4 11  3
#2016-10-01  4  3  9  2  5  7
#2016-10-02  5  7  9  7  7 10
#2016-10-03  7  2  5  3  5  3
#2016-10-04  2  6  7  2  4  5
#2016-10-05  2  2 11  2  4  7
#2016-10-06  4  3 10 10  8  2
#2016-10-07  3  6  4  5  9  4
#2016-10-08  5  4 10 10  3  8
#2016-10-09  3  3 11  8 11  7
```

**They give the same output, and you get dates as row names! What is more, the original object class is respected!**

```
class(y1)
# [1] "zoo"

class(y2)
# [1] "xts" "zoo"
```

---

**Follow-up**

> Out of curiosity....is there a function for the `*apply` family doing the equivalent of your two step procedure (i.e. `lapply` + `do.call`)?

It seems not. You can get all of them from `?lapply` (including the "See Also" part). If there really is, people on this site won't be doing `lapply` + `do.call` combination so often.

Comment: Many thanks for your detailed answer. Really helpful. Out of curiosity....is there a function for the "apply" family doing the equivalent of your two step procedure (i.e. lapply + do.call)?